# Free BSD: What is a global flag

Tags: linux, operating-system, freebsd, flags

Does anybody know what does global flag mean in context of operating system, how check their statuses and how to add custom, if of course it is possible.

I couldn't find any comprehensive information about that.

For more clarification I am looking at FreeBSD

Comment: Do you have any example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Not really, I need to create a custom system call which will change the global flag. It's a part of assignment. I stack at this point, can't understand what is menat by 'Global flag' and can't find any information on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Possibly* it's referring to the `sysctl` interface, which allows you to set and query certain system-wide settings (not all of them are changeable).

Among these are the maximum number of processes or files, maximum files per process, clock rate, hostname and so on.

Refer to [sysctl(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=8) for further details.

Note that that link is for the command-line tool used for changing system parameters. There is also an [API](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%203.1-RELEASE) if you wish to do it from C code.

---

Alternatively, it may simply be suggesting you add a `syscall` which maintains some state. This could be as simple as an integer which could be set and/or retrieved via the `syscall` interface.

If that's the case, you will find plenty of information and tutorials on the web with a Google search of `freebsd syscall add`, including a few here on Stack Overflow itself.